# Exporting (rdlc) report to excel

Tags: .net, excel, report, rdlc

I have a 1 page rdlc report which exports fine to pdf, but when I export it to excel it divides the report into 2 pages horizontally in print preview as if the report width is larger than the page size, and apparantly the InteractiveWidth, PageWidth and ReportWidth properties have no effects with excel.

so is there any other way to control the page width?

Answer (score 0):

I usually show the grid and check that the margins (in properties) + the page size doesn't excede the print dimensions